# How do I get psycopg_pool to connect to my Cockroach Database Cluster using psycog.crdb.connect which is supported in psycopg 3.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cockroachdb, psycopg3

I'm using `psycopg_pool` (3.1.7) and would like to connect to a Cockroach Database Cluster.

`psycopg` 3.1 has [support for CRDB](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/crdb.html#module-psycopg.crdb) via `psycopg.crdb.connect()`, but I'm unsure  how to get [psycopg_pool](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/pool.html#psycopg-pool-connection-pool-implementations) to use `psycopg.crdb.connect()` rather than `psycopg.connect()`.    Thanks in advance!